# MVC3 RegularExpression attribute - How do I refuse brackets

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, attributes, brackets

I'm using MVC3 and need to create a `RegularExpression` attribute for a property in a model to validate that the user has not entered brackets. Anyone know what this regex string would look like?

This is what I have right now.

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("--enter regex here--", ErrorMessage = "You cannot use '[' or ']' on the title ")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Oded Would it? I used `+` in my answer simply because of the `[Required]` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a negated character class with the characters that you don't want.

Note that square brackets are considered to be "special" in regex, so you'll need to escape them like so:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\[\]]+$", ErrorMessage = "You cannot use '[' or ']' on the title ")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do:

```
[^\[\]]*
```

This is a character class that will match on any character that is not `[` or `]`. Note that the `[]` are escaped *within* the character class.

In the attribute this would be:

```
[RegularExpression(@"[^\[\]]*", 
                   ErrorMessage = "You cannot use '[' or ']' on the title ")]
```